# gulp.js: Using 'debug_info' on gulp-sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm trying to get the line numbers of my SASS file in to my compiled CSS file. According to [docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) I must set `debug_info` to true, but is not working at all.

```
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', debug_info: true }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/dev/css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/production/css'));
});
```

Anyone know if this is possible using gulp-sass plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible for `gulp-sass` , I would say that what SteveLacy points out is the solution you where looking for.

In your code it would look like this:

```
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
 return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
   .pipe(sass({ 
      style: 'expanded',
      sourceComments: 'normal'
    }))
   .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/dev/css'))
   //.pipe(minifyCSS())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/production/css'));
});
```

Note that `gulp-minify-css` will strip any comments added by `gulp-sass`, so I commented it.

Comment: Update to this solution: you should now use sourceComments: true

Comment: Note that `sourceComments: true` made my `.min.css` file twice as large as the original, instead of half the size. Changing the value back to `normal` decreased the size dramatically

Answer (score 4):

`gulp-sass` uses `node-sass` as it's SASS compiler.

Referring to the `node-sass` [Docs](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass), it does not have a 'debug_info'. 
Rather it has [source comments / maps](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#sourcecomments) which is probably not what you are going for.

There is an open issue regarding line numbers: https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/196

Answer (score 1):

you can use [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass). I use it in my projects with debug infos and line numbers:

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
...
// Styles for Development (Watch-Process)
gulp.task('styles-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        debugInfo   : true,
        lineNumbers : true,
        loadPath    : 'src/styles',
        style       : 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'));
});
...
```

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: ruby sass supports sass debug. gulp-sass, which uses node-sass (see below) does not. switching to ruby sass might suit your needs, but it is not a correct answer to this question. (as an aside, I stick with node-sass because it's faster)

Comment: Thanks for the `lineNumbers`. Tried to use `sourceComments` before with no luck.
No info on the plugin page about that.

Comment: ruby sass is no longer compatible